# I have created a server client programm in java in netbeans but now i want to run it in jgrasp

Tags: java, jgrasp

I have created a server client programm in java in netbeans but now i want to run it in jgrasp  but jgrasp is not allowing me two run both the classes i.e server and client at the same time. pls help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can only run one thing at a time in jGRASP. You'll have to start one or the other at the command line.